# How to integrate $f(x|\theta)=\int_{0}^\infty \frac{3x\theta^3}{(x+\theta)^4} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I've been struggling for quite some time to solve this integration:

$f(x|\theta)=\int_{0}^\infty \frac{3x\theta^3}{(x+\theta)^4} dx$

Can anyone help me try to solve this please? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You edit your question to include information on what specific things you tried.

Comment: Hint: partial fractions.

Comment: If you set $u=x+\theta$ then your integral becomes $3\theta^3\int_\theta^{\infty}\Big(\frac{u-\theta}{u^4}\Big)du$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{3x\theta^{3}}{(x+\theta)^{4}}\mathrm{d}x & = 3\theta^{3} \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x}{(x+\theta)^{4}}\mathrm{d}x\\\\
& = 3\theta^{3}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{(x+\theta) - \theta}{(x+\theta)^{4}}\mathrm{d}x\\\\
& = 3\theta^{3}\left[\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(x+\theta)^{3}}\mathrm{d}x - \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\theta}{(x+\theta)^{4}}\mathrm{d}x\right]\\\\
& = 3\theta^{3}\left[-\frac{1}{2(x+\theta)^{2}} + \frac{\theta}{3(x+\theta)^{3}}\right]\Biggr|_{0}^{\infty}\\\\
& = 3\theta^{3}\left[\frac{1}{2\theta^{2}} - \frac{1}{3\theta^{2}}\right] = \frac{\theta}{2}
\end{align*}